# How to "automatically" cancel a stream subscription?

Tags: dart, stream

I have a dart model that has a StreamSubscription:

```
class CounterPageModel {
  CounterPageModel() {
    subscription = Services.resetCounter.listen(resetCounter);
  }

  late StreamSubscription<bool> subscription;
```

If I'm understanding StreamSubscription, it doesn't call `cancel` when the `StreamDescription` instance is disposed. Is that correct? If so, is there a simple way to cancel the subscription when my model is disposed?

I wrote a simple `dispose` function that I can call when the model is about to be disposed that would cancel the subscription, but it feels like there must be a more standard way? (E.g., write a wrapper for StreamSubscription that calls `cancel` when StreamSubscription is disposed? But I don't know what that would look like.)

Answer (score 1):

Use [Flutter Hooks](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_hooks) [`useStream`](https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_hooks/latest/flutter_hooks/useStream.html), which can subscribe to a stream (like you would put in `initState`), return its current value, and automatically cancels the subscription when the widget lifecycle is complete (like you would put in `dispose`).

Very good technology from Remi... the same guy who wrote Provider and RiverPod.

Comment: I didn't know Flutter Hooks that that functionality. Good to know. I am trying to keep this logic in straight Dart but will keep this info for future use. Thanks Randal!